# Docker : Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos8

I am using Docker. I am newbie in this tech, so please let me know if require any other info

Want to install a remote host,

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "$PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
    networks:
      - net
  remote_host:
    container_name: remote-host
    image: remote-host
    build:
      context: centos
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
```

Docker File :

```
FROM centos


RUN dnf install openssh-server


RUN useradd remote_user && \
    echo "remote_user:1234" | chpasswd && \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh

COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user/.ssh/ && \
    chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN ssh-keygen -A

CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Exception I am facing

```
[jenkins@localhost jenkins-data]$ docker compose build
[+] Building 4.1s (6/10)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 516B                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/centos:latest                                                                                                   1.9s
 => CACHED [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/centos@sha256:a27fd8080b517143cbbbab9dfb7c8571c40d67d534bbdee55bd6c473f432b177                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 95B                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => ERROR [2/6] RUN dnf install openssh-server                                                                                                                     2.0s
------
 > [2/6] RUN dnf install openssh-server:
#0 1.808 Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: No URLs in mirrorlist
#0 1.809 CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream                       67  B/s |  38  B     00:00
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dnf install openssh-server" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
[jenkins@localhost jenkins-data]$ cd
[jenkins@localhost ~]$
[jenkins@localhost ~]$
[jenkins@localhost ~]$ ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.199.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bom07s36-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.199.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=9.28 ms
64 bytes from bom07s36-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.199.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=9.03 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`centos` docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/) is marked as depreciated and no longer supported/maintained.

Comment: Can i use any other image to create remote host ?

Comment: You can replace `centos` with `rockylinux:8` image.